# How to pause a ListIterator

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database, iterator

Im using Firebase database to store my users scores games , at the end of the game users can see the final results of every members of the party

My users data and their scores are stored at 2 different places

here how looks my structure in Firebase.

```
Posts
-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy
    user_id: "KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy"
    score: "A"
     
-asdasdasddsad
   user_id: "asdasdasddsad"
    score: "B"



Users
-KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy
    id: "KLpcURDV68BcbAvlPFy"
    name: "Jordan"
     
-asdasdasddsad
   id: "asdasdasddsad"
    name: "Tyler"
```

So I load first Id  from  Child (Posts )  inside an Arraylist and after I user the ListIterator to load data for every id  in the Child(Users ) .

My question is simple . How can I pause a ListIterator

I have an Firebase onDataChanged Load inside a My ListIterator  , it return null because my list finish faster than my Firebase load , How can I make my List wait for my Firebase database to load necessary data and then resume itself ?

My code

```
  for (ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {

            String UserUid= it.next();

            LoadataValue(UserUid, new OnObjectExistListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChanged(Data  userData) {

 ListIterator must resume here 

                }
          
            
        });


   ListIterator must pause Here 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pause a list iterator they way you want it to. Let me explain a little bit.

Firebase gets the data over the internet in a separate background thread and it should take some time to trigger that `onDataChanged` method whereas your list iterator might be running in the main thread. Hence, you will always have to wait for the background thread to be completed and return some data to your main thread to be able to show them. You can achieve the behavior in many different ways.

It looks like you are trying to get all the user details from the firebase. I assume, the simplified structure of your firebase database looks like the following.

```
users:
    user1: 
       userDetails: 
            name: Everyone
    user2: 
       userDetails:
            name: Needs
    user3: 
       userDetails: 
            name: some
    user4: 
       userDetails:
            name: help
```

You can try getting all the values at once from the `users` node, and store them locally (maybe inside a `List<User>`). Then once the list of users are downloaded correctly in your `onDataChange` function, trigger your list iterator in a separate method so that it can go over that locally stored list and provide you the results that you want.

Here's a pseudo implementation.

```
// Get a reference to your users
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("your-firebase-url/users");

// Attach a listener to read the data from your firebase database
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<User> users = dataSnapshot.getValue(User[].class);
    callAFunctionThatRunsThroughThisListOfUsers(users);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi  Sir thanks for the answer , the fact is that I got an Arraylist of  id from different users and im trying to do that to every id in the Arraylist   ( that I already loaded before  )  My database must Load all info ( name , email address , etc ) , I hope you undertand my request I will edit the question

Comment: I understand. In that case, you can start loading them from database and when the `onDataChange` is called, try to add the user details in a separate list (e.g `list2`). When all the data is loaded, use that `list2` to show the details of the users. Put debug logs in your code so that you can understand the flow better. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your answer  , I will try it right now  , I edited my question to

Comment: Great to know!! I am glad that I could help! Cheers!